# Python: Copy and pasting to specific row and column

Tags: python, excel, pandas, list, dataframe

I have 2 input files and 1 main file in excel. I want to use python to copy values from the input file and paste into the main file of the corresponding row and column as such:

```
Input file 1 (COPIED)
Col Row extra1 extra2 value

A    70                6.1
B    87                5.0
G    90                4.4

Input file 2 (COPIED)
Col Row extra1 extra2 value

C    10                0.9
F    17                3.3
G    20                1.1
```

```
Main file (PASTED)
Col Row value
A   70   6.1
B   87   5.0 
C   10   0.9
F   17   3.3
G   20   1.1
G   90   4.4
```

The row and col columns are already filled in the first place.
Anyone has any solutions or insights into how to go about doing this? thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Copying columns between two different workbooks using openpyxl could be done as follows:

```
import openpyxl

wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook('B.xlsx')
ws1 = wb1.active

wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook('E.xlsx')
ws2 = wb2.active

for src, dst in zip(ws1['B:B'], ws2['AN:AN']):
    dst.value = src.value

wb2.save('E.xlsx')
```

For a range of columns, the following would work:

```
import openpyxl

wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook('B.xlsx')
ws1 = wb1.active

wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook('E.xlsx')
ws2 = wb2.active

for src, dst in zip(ws1['A:I'], ws2['AN:AV']):
    for cell_src, cell_dst in zip(src, dst):
        cell_dst.value = cell_src.value

wb2.save('E.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 1):

if your main file is empyty

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({"Col":[1,2,3],"Row":[2,3,4],"value":[6,5,7],"ree":[0,0,0]})


    Col Row value ree
0   1   2   6   0
1   2   3   5   0
2   3   4   7   0

df2=pd.DataFrame({"Col":[9,8,0],"Row":[6,4,22],"value":[26,55,27]})


    Col Row value ree
0   1   2   6   0
1   2   3   5   0
2   3   4   7   0

df1=df1[["Col","Row","value"]]
df2=df2[["Col","Row","value"]]

main=pd.concat((df1,df2))

    Col Row value
0   1   2   6
1   2   3   5
2   3   4   7
0   9   6   26
1   8   4   55
2   0   22  27
```

so after this you can create a main file or save it in the existing csv
this works if main is empty if its filled then concat as done above.